# Effect of System.Net Connection Management

Tags: .net, system.net

```
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add maxconnection="1000" address="*"/>
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
```

Can someone tell me if this setting affects my WCF (basicHttpBinding) services?

Comment: This is a good question, however, the answer aren't good. maxconnection are a OS configuration that can be overriden.

Comment: It affects WCF clients. I was having an issue where a large number of client requests were being backlogged because we didn't have enough open connections to send them over. Changing this setting caused more messages to be sent at once and resolved the backlog and my client was a WCF client in a multi-threaded .NET application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

From MSDN.

> This class is used to specify the
>   maximum number of simultaneous
>   connections to a remote computer.

Comment: It does affect the http binding for an asmx service. Dunno how this is the answer.

Comment: @Denis Valeev: The question is WCF specific. I suspect classic webservices tap directly into the `System.Net` API.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, for WCF it would look something like this:

```
<behavior name="CommonServices_Behavior">
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
  <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentSessions="50" maxConcurrentInstances="50" />
</behavior>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the maximum amount of connections is a value that your server
setup can support. This is based on the physical makeup of your server(s),
the normal load the server(s) are under, and your Internet connection speed.
There is no one value that is right for everyone.

refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb6y0fyc.aspx for more details